# need assistance with spinner and mysql database in android

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to get the string value from a spinner in android and post it to a MySQL database. I'm fetching data that is populating my spinner from the database and then repost it with some additional data using volley. The problem is when I try to post it the app just crashes for some reason.

heres a snippet of the code. Spinner value is a hashmap that will contain the value from the spinner

```
 jsonSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                namas =  jsonSpinner.getItemAtPosition(jsonSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                spinnerValue.put("value",namas);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            }
        });

Heres the code to post the data using volley

btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                gotBranchName = spinnerValue.get("value");
                gotVenue = venue.getText().toString();
                gotService = service.getText().toString();
                gotDate = date.getText().toString();
                gotNumberOfMales = numOfMales.getText().toString();
                gotNumberOfFemales = numOfFemales.getText().toString();
                gotNumberOfChildren = numOfChildren.getText().toString();

                if (gotVenue.equals("") || gotService.equals("") || gotDate.equals("") ||
                        gotNumberOfMales.equals("") || gotNumberOfFemales.equals("") || gotNumberOfChildren.equals("")) {


                    CookieBar.build(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Error")
                            .setMessage("cannot post data. check for empty fields")
                            .show();

                } else {

                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                    //send the values to the database as key value pairs
                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {


                            try {

                                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);

                                int status = jo.getInt("status");

                                if (status == 1) {


                                    CookieBar.build(MainActivity.this)
                                            .setTitle("Success")
                                            .setMessage("Record Added ")
                                            .show();


                                    clearFields();


                                } else {


                                    CookieBar.build(MainActivity.this)
                                            .setTitle("Error")
                                            .setMessage("Could Not Add Data")
                                            .show();


                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            CookieBar.build(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("Error")
                                    .setMessage("Please check your connection settings")
                                    .show();
                            Log.i("My error", "" + error);
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("branchName", gotBranchName);
                            map.put("venue", gotVenue);
                            map.put("service", gotService);
                            map.put("date", gotDate);
                            map.put("numberOfMales", gotNumberOfMales);
                            map.put("numberOfFemales", gotNumberOfFemales);
                            map.put("numberOfChildren", gotNumberOfChildren);


                            return map;
                        }
                    };

                    queue.add(request);
                }

            }
```

Comment: what your logcat say ?

Comment: alright let me check

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line from

```
namas =  jsonSpinner.getItemAtPosition(jsonSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
```

to

```
namas = jsonSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```